# Install qt 5.15 onto CentOS 7

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, qt

I have a program I want to compile on Red Hat 7.8 which uses Qt 5.15 features, yet the last available Qt 5 library (from repo's) is Qt 5.9

How can I install Qt 5.15 on CentOS 7 to compile my program?

If this is possible, would users of my program have to install those same libraries / workaround?  (I'm using dynamic linking since this is open source software)

Comment: You best bet would be to figure out how to compile it with 5.9.  What feature exactly are you trying to obtain by using v5.15?

Comment: I make use of a few classes available only in later 5.x libs, like QRandomGenerator.  I hat to have to rework my code just to support RH7 (even thought it's nearing end of life, still lots of users)

Comment: Cool coding sibling.  Been there myself. Good luck.